# Postgresql - Could not find any downloads

Tags: python, postgresql

Why this exception generates on `apt-get install` or on `pip` :

```
 root@tameen:/home/tameen/Downloads/postgis-2.0.1# pip install postgresql-2.0.1
    Collecting postgresql-2.0.1
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement postgresql-2.0.1
      No distributions at all found for postgresql-2.0.1
```

sudo apt-get install postgresql

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What are you attempting to install, [the postgresql server](http://www.postgresql.org/) or [a python driver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2)?

Comment: attempting to install `postgresql`

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming (or django).

Comment: If you mean the database server, use [this guide to install with apt](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt), though there's no version 2.0.1 of the server that I'm aware of. What guide or tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is a database system, not a Python library. pip is for installing Python libraries only. You will need to install this via your system's package manager.

For instance, if you are on Debian or Ubuntu, you would need to do `sudo apt-get install postgresql`.